# Actualizar Array de una colección - MonngoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una coleccion en mongodb llamada playlists, en la cual se almacena los siguientes valores: userID y music, *music* es un Array el cual contendra una lista de las canciones que el usuario almacene, sin embargo tego un problema al agregar una cancion y es que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, pense que con `findOneAndUpdate()` se lograria, pero solo actualiza el valor ya existente y lo que quiero es que el nuevo valor se agregue de tal forma que la lista valla creciendo.

```
async function update(user,music){
    const playlist = await model.findOneAndUpdate({userID: user},{music:[music]})
    await console.log(playlist)
    console.log(user,music)
}
```

**Modelo**

```
const playlist = new Schema ({
    userID: String,
    music: Array,
})
```

exite alguna forma de añadir los datos algo equivalente a un `merge()` de Firebase?
Utilizo el modulo mongoose v 5.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de buscar encontre que para añadir elementos a un array se hace con la opcion `$push`, de la siguiente forma

```
async function update(user,music){
    const playlist = await model.findOneAndUpdate({userID: user},{
        $push:{
            music:music
        }
    })
    await console.log(playlist)
}
```

`$push` se utiliza como una opcion al hacer la operacion de actualizacion del documento, esto hace que el elemto se añada al array, este puede estar declarado de dos formas en el modelo.
Tambien se puede user `$addToSet` esto agregara el valor si no existe, pero si existe no hara nada, es decir en caso music contenga `[cancion1,cancion2]` y se desea agregar *cancion1* no pasara nada, pero si se desea agregar *cancion3* esta si se agregara, su uso es igual.

```
async function update(user,music){
    const playlist = await model.findOneAndUpdate({userID: user},{
        $addToSet:{
            music:music
        }
    })
    await console.log(playlist)
}
```

**Modelo**

```
const playlist = new Schema ({
    userID: String,
    music: Array, //tambien puede ser [String]
})
```

y funcionara de igual forma. espero ayudar a alguien.